How to impute missing values in electricity time series data considering the previous and next 2 values on the same day and time previous 2 days?
I have a pandas dataframe like below:



meter IDs
date
00:00
00:30
01:00
01:30
.......
23:00
23:30




1
2020-09-01
0.30
0.40
0.41
0.42
.......
0.47
0.39


1
2020-09-02
0.36
0.39
nan
nan
.......
0.53
0.41


1
2020-09-03
0.26
0.33
0.38
nan
.......
nan
0.45


1
2020-09-04
0.36
0.40
0.41
0.42
.......
0.69
nan


1
2020-09-05
0.30
0.40
0.41
0.42
.......
0.69
0.62


:
:
:
:
:
:
.......
:
:


1
2020-12-31
0.30
0.40
0.41
0.42
.......
0.69
0.62


2
2020-09-01
0.55
0.57
nan
0.60
.......
0.68
0.62


2
2020-09-02
0.61
0.59
0.66
nan
.......
nan
nan


2
2020-09-03
0.64
nan
0.66
0
.......
0.66
0.67


2
2020-09-04
0.58
0.65
0.65
0.71
.......
0.69
0.66


2
2020-09-05
0.49
0.52
0.55
nan
.......
nan
0.62


:
:
:
:
:
:
.......
:
:


2
2020-12-31
0.48
0.51
nan
0.52
.......
0.63
0.61



I want to fill the missing values for the individual meter IDs considering mean of the previous and next 2 values on the same day and same time of previous 2 days?
How can i fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Please show your expected output for the given input data.

pandas' fillna() function is a built-in tool for these scenarios. You can use this reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html. I think you might be able to integrate the mean and previous values. But, for a simple example, if you want to replace all NaN elements in columns ‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’, and ‘D’, with 0, 1, 2, and 3 respectively, and have a df below:
     A    B   C    D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0.0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1.0
2  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  4.0

values = {"A": 0, "B": 1, "C": 2, "D": 3}
df.fillna(value=values)

Then you get:
    A    B    C    D
0  0.0  2.0  2.0  0.0
1  3.0  4.0  2.0  1.0
2  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
3  0.0  3.0  2.0  4.0

Or, a custom filling function that iterates over the data frame might help:
import pandas as pd

df.sort_values(by=['meter IDs', 'date'], inplace=True)

def fill_missing(df):
    for meter_id, group in df.groupby('meter IDs'):
        for col in df.columns[2:]:
            for i in range(len(df)):
                if pd.isnull(df.at[i, col]):
                    prev_vals = group[(group['date'] < df.at[i, 'date']) & (group[col].notnull())].tail(2)[col]
                    next_vals = group[(group['date'] > df.at[i, 'date']) & (group[col].notnull())].head(2)[col]
                    mean_val = pd.concat([prev_vals, next_vals]).mean()
                    df.at[i, col] = mean_val

fill_missing(df)
print(df)

